# Join a relationship not working with enableAjaxTable

Tags: php, laravel

im using laravel and backpack package ,
Is there a problem in backpack? Because this scope works correctly

in my controller i have added 2 joins :
my model scope :

```
public function scopeRep($query)
    {
        return $query
            ->join('shops','shops.id' , '=' ,'products.shop_id')
            ->join('shop_user','shop_user.shop_id' , '=' ,'shops.id')
            ->where('shop_user.user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->select('products.*');


    }
```

I did it by adding `$this->crud->addClause('rep')` to my controller.

scope worked with `dd(Product::rep()->get())` and disable ajaxTable fine worked. but not work in ajax crud

error in ajax console :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `name` as `name`, `shop_id` as `shop_id`, `discount` as `discount`, `discount_exp` as `discount_exp`, `price` as `price`, `status` as `status`, `id` as `id` from `products` inner join `shops` on `shops`.`id` = `products`.`shop_id` inner join `shop_user` on `shop_user`.`shop_id` = `shops`.`id` where `shop_user`.`user_id` = 1 limit 25 offset 0)

Comment: I have no idea about enableAjaxTable, but I have a doubt that both tables has name column ?

Comment: All column names are different , There is a problem in backpack(laravel admin package)

Answer (score 0):

It means, that field `name` exist in two tables. You can use [aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) or use `$query->select('id ,shops.name, ...')->join(...)`

Comment: this scope works correctly , But it's a problem in backpack package for ajaxTable